# How to check for origin while using Eventsource in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, polyfills, eventsource

I'm using this polyfill to make Server Side Events (EventSource) work with IE - https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource

It works great, except I can't check for origin, like this tutorial recommends (for security purposes) http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

Here is the code from html5rocks

```
  source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  if (e.origin != 'http://example.com') {
    alert('Origin was not http://example.com');
    return;
  }
  ...
}, false);
```

Is there a way to set and check the origin, make it work with IE?

Answer (score 0):

The article on html5rocks says that the origin should be checked, but this it not necessary.

The warning "Authors should check the origin attribute" is especially relevant for window.postMessage() messages and not so much EventSource and WebSocket.

Because you are passing the URL as an argument to the constructor of the EventSource.

See https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=14900 .